# Interpolate and concatenate Puppet variable inside nested string quotes

Tags: puppet

I am creating a Puppet configuration file for a service.
I would like to add the hostname as a variable in the line. However, it got an error because of nested quotation marks (`"`) in the line.

```
$hostlocal = "${hostname}"

file {'puppet_facts_example':
  ensure  => file,
  path    => '/tmp/test.txt',
  content => "modparam("topology_hiding", "th_callid_prefix", "$hostlocal_")"
}
```

If I just print `$hostlocal`, it shows the hostname correctly.
Is there any way to use a Puppet variable inside nested string quotes (`"`)?

I also tried to use template.
In the template,

```
modparam("topology_hiding", "th_callid_prefix", "<$= @hostlocal %>_")"
```

But the result was no value.

```
modparam("topology_hiding", "th_callid_prefix", "_")"
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The basic problem here is that you need to escape nested string quotes when you are doing string interpolation/escape style quotes (`"`). Also, you are attempting to concatenate `_` onto `$hostlocal`, but Puppet is interpreting that as a variable `$hostlocal_`, so you need curly braces to establish concatenation. You can fix your problem with:

```
$hostlocal = "${hostname}"

file {'puppet_facts_example':
  ensure  => file,
  path    => '/tmp/test.txt',
  content => "modparam(\"topology_hiding\", \"th_callid_prefix\", \"${hostlocal}_\")"
}
```

However, we can improve on this further. The first couple of things we can do here is remove the quotes around `${hostname}` since it is not being interpolated. The same goes for `topology_hiding` and `th_callid_prefix`, except we must change them to single literal string quotes since nothing is being interpolated or escaped. Also, if you are doing Facter 2 style lookups on facts, then it is better style to establish the fact as a global variable with `$::`.

```
$hostlocal = $::hostname

file {'puppet_facts_example':
  ensure  => file,
  path    => '/tmp/test.txt',
  content => "modparam('topology_hiding', 'th_callid_prefix', \"${hostlocal}_\")"
}
```

Finally, note that the use of the `$hostlocal` variable is redundant with the fact, so it can be safely removed for clarity and efficiency. This yields the optimal solution below.

```
file {'puppet_facts_example':
  ensure  => file,
  path    => '/tmp/test.txt',
  content => "modparam('topology_hiding', 'th_callid_prefix', \"${::hostname}_\")"
}
```

Comment: Works Great! Thanks for you additional suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

since hostname is a facter variable.
it must be referenced as $hostlocal = $::hostname

Thanks
vinodh

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion hostname is a variable so you don't need double quotation mark because you want to get value of variable.

Try

```
$hostlocal = $hostname
```

Comment: It works ok with or without double quotation mark. The problem is the content part which contains multiple double quotation marks. If I just print $hostlocal, it shows correct hostname.